# Blue light is reflected, red is not. What happens to other visible/non-visible light?

Tags: visible-light, reflection

The problem says:

The certain film on the glass reflects blue light of wavelength 480nm, but does not reflect any red light of wavelength 640nm.

1) If we say that it reflects blue light but no red light, does it mean that we actually see blue light only?

2) As I understand, if something reflects a blue light that automatically means that red light and all other light is absorbed. Is that right?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes that's true. Also when something reflects  light of particular wavelength (say blue), then that object appears to be **blue in color**.

Answer (score 1):

> The certain film on the glass reflects blue light of wavelength 480nm, but does not reflect any red light of wavelength 640nm. ... If we say that it reflects blue light but no red light, does it mean that we actually see blue light only?

It depends which side of the glass you are observing from.

If you're on the same side as the source, you'll see the reflected blue light.

If you're on the other side, you'll see the transmitted red light.

> As I understand, if something reflects a blue light that automatically means that red light and all other light is absorbed. Is that right?

No. For example, consider your bathroom mirror. It reflect blue light, and it also reflects red light.

Another possibility is it could reflect blue light and transmit (rather than absorbing) red light.